# HTML responsive issues

Tags: html, css

[enter link description here](http://183.83.218.176/regencyinfotech/index.html)I have some html responsive issues.I  wrote a code but that code having Cascading style sheets and bootstrap but it gives response only 15 inches screen how to get response to other large screen please give me solution

Comment: Without code how can anyone help you....

Comment: show your code, so that we can help you

Comment: Please share some code what you tried...

Comment: Some punctuation would help too.

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries on your css - [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Exemple

```
@media (min-width: 1920px) { 
 .yourclass {
  ...
 }
}
```

Comment: hi thank you for your suggestion but am the beginner for how to use bootstrap queries i don't know  about media quires please help me...

Comment: hi how to get bootstrap icons like ERP / CRM and IOT is there any default icons for those items